# Why JS .map and .forEach methods returning wrong array length?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am all confused. Simple code:

```js
let x = [{},{}]
console.log(x.length,x.forEach((el)=>{console.log(el)}))
```

returning

`2 {} {} undefined`

same output with .map

UPD:
Where the heck did the 'undefined' come from?

Another test:

```js
let x = [{
  '1': '2'
}, {
  '2': '3'
}];
console.log(x.forEach((el) => {
  console.log(el)
}));
```

output:

```
{ '1': '2' }
{ '2': '3' }
2 undefined
```

Comment: it's not giving the output you're stating for updated one, try running snippet

Comment: let x = [{'1':'2'},{'2':'3'}];
console.log(x.forEach(el=>console.log(el)));
ouputs array and 'undefined'

Comment: it will print both the object from array and at the end it will print `undefined`

Comment: `undefined is returned value from forEach is printed by outer console` did you noticed this line from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57315046/9624435)

Comment: what is 'outer console'?

Comment: You have two console statement, i am referring to outermost i.e. `console.log(x.length.....)`

Comment: Yes I got it. Looks like my daily brain overload. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array contains 2 elements that's why the length returned is 2.

`forEach` does not return anything, and when you `console.log()` a `forEach` it prints `undefined` as it expects some value from the `fromEach` but gets nothing. Don't put the `forEach` loop inside a  `console.log()`

```js
let x = [{'1':'2'},{'2':'3'}];
console.log(x.length)
x.forEach(el=>console.log(el))
```

Comment: the answer has the reason stated

Comment: I still don't understand. It returns {'1':'2'},{'2':'3'},undefined. What is 'undefined' here?

Comment: The undefined is printed because the forEach is put inside a console.log(). Take the forEach out of the console.log. Console.log will print a value returned by a function inside it but forEach does not return any value. This is why undefined gets printed. When forEach is out of console.log undefined won't be printed

Comment: Right, my bad. Looks like too much work for today (sigh). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

> why is array length not 1

The `length` is defined as "The index of the last item in the array + 1". You have two items in the array, and it isn't sparse.

> where the heck did the 'undefined' come from?

The return value of `forEach()` is `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

> where the heck did the 'undefined' come from ?

forEach returns `undefined`

- `2` is the value printed due to `x.length`
- `{}` is printed due to console.log inside `forEach`
- `undefined` is returned value from `forEach` is printed by outer console

> why is array length not 1

- Length is defined as total no. of items in an array